# How to set up MonsterDebugger and FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I'm trying to follow [directions given by MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/tour/quick-start) I've linked the SWC, added the code. Then built the project.

The last thing they say: "Publish your project and watch the magic happen."

What I got is a SWF that is built to an http directory where my PHP file picks it up and displays it in browser.

What I'm expecting/want is to interact with my SWF application through browser and debug it with MonsterDebugger.

I'm obviously missing something since there it looks like there is no way for Monster tool to attach itself to the SWF?  I'm not sure how does Monster will know about my published SWF?

I'm using FlashDevelop/FlashCS5 and Actionscript 3.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but did you actually started Monster Debugger.exe after publishing and opening your project in browser? Also MonsterDebugger.initialize(); has second argument which is an address if you publishing and accessing your project on the server I suppose. Did you try to change it?

Comment: All good questions. Yes MonsterDebugger.exe is running.  The second argument to initialize is by default set to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost.  My application is running from url: https://localhost/myapp.swf

Answer (score 1):

My bad.  I had MonsterDebugger.initialize() statement to execute last in constructor of my document file.  I moved initialize statement to be the very first line in my constructor.  Now it attaches. Apparently there was some code that executed before initialize that caused issue. All is well now that it is the first line in the document file.